# preselect a radio input in visualforce

Tags: input, salesforce, visualforce

I have added checked="checked" to the input but it doesn't get preselected.

```
<label class="label Single" for="whoCovered_S"><input id="whoCovered_S" tabindex="1" type="radio" value="Just myself" name="WhoCovered" showhelp="1" checked="checked" />Just myself</label>
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

checked is a boolean attribute.  Try checked="true".